# How to process calls one by one through the cvp script?

Tags: ip, call, center, voice, cisco

I have a problem that demands processing calls one by one. Once first call enters our decision loop another call should be redirected to a diferent loop untill first call is processed . We have an issue when 2 calls enter in the script one second appart they are processed by call studio at the same time.
Is somehow possible to dynamicly separate those calls?

we already tried to separate calls with set local variable elemtn but it does not get update quickly enough to distinguish different calls

We need calls to enter the script one at the time,not together

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by adding a wait node in icm with 5 seconds 
.when the call enters vxml script in icm we add 5 secs delay.
Before the wait node add a % allocator node which will have two paths 
One will have 5 seconds wait and one without. So when
Two calls are fired at same time one will go through wait
And one will go immediately go to decision and you can flip flop between the two.